# algebraic vs rational equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Are there classes of algebraic varieties for which algebraic and rational equivalence for algebraic cycles coincide? (references also appreciated)

Comment: For varieties with cellular decompositions, rational=homological equivalence, and therefore algebraic equivalence. See Fulton's intersection theory 19.1.11. This also holds for toric varieties for similar reasons.

Comment: Over $\bar{\mathbf F}_p$, they agree when you use $\mathbf Q$-coefficients, basically because Jacobians of varieties over finite fields are torsion.